# KeyCode reading from textbox

Tags: excel, vba

I have made a userform where users can load images and classify them in 4 classes. "Merged, Misplaced, Stitching and Out of focus".
[image]

They can navigate thought column 5 to get the images names using the arrow key (which are defined in the KeyHandler) or just by clicking the buttons. This will load the image in the right field with the data attached.

```
Sub KeyUpHandler(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
If Shift = 0 And KeyCode = 37 Then
Call PreviousPict
End If
If Shift = 0 And KeyCode = 39 Then
Call NextPict
End If
End Sub
```

I`ve also added the 4 textboxes next to the classes where I want the users to enter a key which will trigger the button. Now my question is **how can I read the Keycode for this textbox value**? I can also create the full table with all keys and keycodes but maybe there is an automatic way to get the keycode for a certain character?

fyi I call the KeyUpHandler on every button/textbox/label in the userform.

```
Private Sub TxtPictureName_KeyUp(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
KeyUpHandler KeyCode, Shift
End Sub
Private Sub UserForm_KeyUp(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
KeyUpHandler KeyCode, Shift
End Sub
Private Sub OutOfFocus_KeyUp(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
KeyUpHandler KeyCode, Shift
End Sub
Private Sub TextBox4_KeyUp(ByVal KeyCode As MSForms.ReturnInteger, ByVal Shift As Integer)
KeyUpHandler KeyCode, Shift
End Sub
```

and so on...

Comment: Try `Asc(TextBox4.Text)` and so on.

Comment: Thanks, that works. I only had to renew the `text.property` with a button